# Click image in horizontal scroll gallery to center function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery, center

I have been trying to get this function to work for some time now and I have searched Stackoverflow as well as other websites for an answer but have had absolutely no luck.

I am using a horizontal scroll gallery by Thomas Kahn (www.smoothdivscroll.com) and it works perfectly, however it does not have a built in click-to-center-image function. I have been trying to code my own function but it has not been working out for me - I am not sure if this is because of horizontal scroll gallery I am using or some other reason.

This is where I call the gallery in my index.php :

```
<div class="container-fluid gallery-container">
    <div id="makeMeScrollable">
        <?php 
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'homegallery', 'posts_per_page' => 1000, 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'desc' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        $count=0;

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  

        $count++;

        $imgID = 'img-home-' . $count;
        ?>
            <img class="img-responsive horizontalscroll-img" id="portfolio-img <?php echo $imgID; ?>" src="<?php echo get_field('gallery-img'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" onClick="centerFunction('<?php echo $imgID; ?>');" />

        <?php
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?>  

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css for the gallery :

```
.gallery-container {
    padding:0px !important;
    height:auto;
}

.horizontalscroll-img {
    padding:0px 15px 0px 0px !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

#makeMeScrollable
    {
        width:100%;

        position: relative;
    }

    /* Replace the last selector for the type of element you have in
       your scroller. If you have div's use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div,
       if you have links use #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a and so on. */
    #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img
    {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
           block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
           accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
        -webkit-user-select: #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div;
        -khtml-user-select: #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div;
        -moz-user-select: #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div;
        -o-user-select: #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div;
        user-select: #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea div;
     }
```

And this is my javascript/jquery function(s) in my footer.php in a script tag :
*I did try many different methods however none of them worked, I will list 2 below*

```
        function centerFunction(i) {

        //First set of code I tried
        var w = document.getElementById(i).clientWidth;
        $(i).style.left = "50%"; //I tried both '$(i)' and 'this'
        $(i).style.marginLeft = Math.round(w/2) + 'px'; 
        $(i).style.margin = "0 auto";

    }
```

This gave me the error
"TypeError: document.getElementByID(...) is null
var w = document.getElementById(i).clientWidth; "

I stepped though the function and for some reason it is not holding the unique id of my image, however I can see that it has passed though to the function correctly.

The second function I tried was:

```
        function centerFunction(i) {

        //Second set of code I tried            
        var w = $(i).width();
        var margin = w/2;

        $(i).css("margin-left","-"+margin);

        $(i).css("margin","0 auto");
        $(i).css("left","50%");

    }
```

This did not give me an error but nothing happened when I clicked on the image.

I have tried other methods that I found online or tried to write myself but nothing seems to be working. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: the sign # is missing at front of id name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a mismatch between the ID of the image and the one that's passed to your JS function.

you set the ID like this:

```
 id="portfolio-img <?php echo $imgID; ?>"
```

but call the function like this:

```
 onClick="centerFunction('<?php echo $imgID; ?>');"
```

Try removing the `portfolio-img`  part...

Also, beware that you need to add a hash if you use jQuery:

```
function centerFunction(i) {
    i = '#' + i;
    var w = $(i).width();
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I removed the other id ('portfolio-img') however it did not seem to make a difference.

As far as I can see it passes the correct ID to the function but the function loses it and thus cannot find the object to work with. Though this is still just speculation.

Comment: you might miss the # sign to specify the Id name :)

Comment: Thank you! That worked! It uses the ID correctly now. The rest of my code doesn't work though, but that is an issue with my logic. 

I will post my new code for anyone that had a similar issue to see what I did.

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly that I overlooked. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI to anyone using the same horizontal scroller as me, I changed my code to this to get it to work:

```
function centerFunction(i) {

        var newis = '#'.concat(i);

        var w = $(newis).width();

        if (w<600) { //for smaller images
            var margin = w*(-1);
        } else { //for larger images
            var margin = w/6*(-1);
        }

        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("scrollToElement", "id", i); //this scrolls to the element you want
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("move", margin); //this was to get it in the middle
    }
```